# Base de dados em access para visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Foi-me mandado fazer um programa para seleção de professores de uma universidade em Visual Basic com base de dados em access, mas eu estou com alguns problemas em realiza-lo.
É possível usar uma checkbox para extraír dados da base em access e assim apresentar um resultado? 
Por exemplo, 
Quero que selecionar e quero que me apresente os resultados dos professores que dêem um certo numero de disciplinas 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, para começar faça um [tour] e depois veja [ask] e [answer]. Sempre informe [um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel)

Comment: Com base na sua pergunta, sim é possível através de instruções sql.